Types are not installed in dist folder for amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk
I incorporated amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk in Angular 13 project.
After I installed the
amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk package.
Sometimes, it installs everything

Sometimes, it only installs some files:

The following files were not installed:
types.js types.d.ts ......
When I reference some types,
import { DashboardContentOptions, EmbeddingContext, } from 'amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk/dist/types';
It gives me an error:
Cannot find module 'amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk/dist/types' or its corresponding type declarations.
How do I install everything in amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk/dist folder?

If you found the solution for this, can you please post the answer.

The problem is the different versions of amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk.
(1) In earlier version (2.3.1) of the SDK, the library scatters in several files.
(2) In current version (2.6.0) of the SDK, every thing is in index.d.ts file.
In the current version, I do need to install another package, "@aws-sdk/client-quicksight": "^3.552.0", to make it working.

Thanks, it saved me as no proper documentation was available.
